# Is it possible to access the subject of the surrounding context in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

The following code doesn't work, but it best show what I'm trying to achieve

```
context "this context describes the class" do

  subject do
    # described class is actually a module here
    c = Class.new.extend(described_class)
    c.some_method_that_has_been_added_through_extension
    c
  end

  # ... testing the class itself here ...

  context "instances of this class" do

    subject do
      # this doesn't work because it introduces a endless recursion bug
      # which makes perfectly sense
      subject.new
    end

  end

end
```

I also tried to use a local variable in the inner context that I initialized
with the subject, but no luck. Is there any way I can access the subject of a outer scope from within my subject definition in the inner scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that obviously works is using an *instance variable* in the *inner context* and initializing it not with the `subject` but `subject.call` instead. Subjects are Procs. Hence, my first approach didn't work.

```
context "instances of this class" do

  klass = subject.call
  subject { klass.new }

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Using #subject can sometimes cause trouble. It is "primarily intended" for use with the short-hand checks like #its.

It also can make example harder to read, as it can work to mask the name/intent of what you testing. Here's a blog post that David Chelimsky wrote on the topic of #subject and #let and their role in revealing intention: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/

Try using let, instead
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Here is how I would most likely write it.

```
context "this context describes the class" do
  let(:name_of_the_module) { Class.new.extend(described_class) }
  before do
    c.some_method_that_has_been_added_through_extension
  end

  # ... testing the class itself here ...

  context "instances of this class" do

    let(:better_name_that_describes_the_instance) { klass.new }

    # ... test the instance
  end

end
```

*SIDENOTE*
You might want to revisit whether you want to use subject at all. I prefer using #let in almost all cases. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to this, but for different reasons. When I test a method that could return a value or raise an error, I often have to repeat the subject in two contexts, once as a proc for `raise_error` and once normally.

What I discovered is that you can give `subjects` names, like `lets`. This let's you reference an named `subject` from an outer scope within a new `subject`. Here's an example:

```
describe 'do_some_math' do
  let!(:calculator) { create(:calculator) }

  # proc to be used with raise_error
  subject(:do_some_math) { 
    -> { calculator.do_some_math(with, complicated, args) } 
  }

  context 'when something breaks' do
    it { is_expected.to raise_error } # ok
  end

  context 'when everything works' do

    # here we call the named subject from the outer scope:
    subject { do_some_math.call } # nice and DRY

    it { is_expected.to be_a(Numeric) } # also ok!
  end
end
```